# local variable 'request' cannot be referred to before it is declared

Tags: vb.net

`Dim list = New List(Of ECozum.HPM.Helper.Models.CustomData)
        list.Add(cdata)

        Dim request = New HttpPostRequestMessage() With { _
             .User = New User() With { _
                 .Verify = 1, _
                 .VerifyFailAct = 1, _
                 .Id = 2 _
            }, _
             .Order = New Order() With { _
                 .DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u"), _
                 .Reference = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() _
            }, _
             .Payment = New Payment() With { _
                 .CData = list, _
                 .Method = New List(Of Integer)() From { _
                    -1 _
                }, _
                 .Amount = tutar, _
                 .AmntEdit = 1, _
                 .SuccessUrl = "http://localhost:50/sonuc.aspx?s=basarili", _
                 .FailUrl = "http://localhost:50/sonuc.aspx?s=basarisiz", _
                 .ReturnUrl = "http://localhost:50/sonuc.aspx?s=return" _
            }, _
             .HashMethod = CInt(Hash.HashType.HMACSHA256) _
        }`

In this page I get the error:

> "local variable 'request' cannot be referred to before it is declared"
> at line: tutar = Request.QueryString("tutar")

Comment: ` Dim request = New HttpPostRequestMessage() ` change this line. Use any random name like `requestobject` or `rnd123`. Since you have it declared as a variable, it is conflicting with default request object.

Comment: wow thanks man. how can i missed that :)

Comment: We all make mistakes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim request = New HttpPostRequestMessage()` change this line. Use any random name like 'requestobject' or 'rnd123'. Since you have it declared as a variable, it is conflicting with default request object.